# How to check algorithm used for decrpyting message

Tags: string, encryption, hash, cryptography

How to check if my string contains Hashing or not?
If it contains Hashing how to decrypt it? How to check which
algorithm is used in decrypting it?
String = 10947f32df25eb4ce3de359176b20271

Comment: *If it contains Hashing how to decrypt it?* -> https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the hash string will be a giveaway. MD5 produces a 128-bit hash value (32 digits long) so easily identifiable, SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm 1) produces a 160-bit (20-byte), etc...

You are using the wrong terminology to state decrypt hash (as hashing is not encryption), maybe you mean reverse or collide? The objective of hashing is resistance, and not confidentiality (which is encryption)

Some implementations such as UNIX will state the type of hashing used in the corresponding `/etc/shadow file.`

```
[root@slashroot1 ~]# cat /etc/shadow
root:$1$Etg2ExUZ$F9NTP7omafhKIlqaBMqng1:15651:0:99999:7:::
```

A first field is a numerical number that tells you the hashing algorithm that's being used.

```
$1 = MD5, $2 =Blowfish, $2a=eksblowfish, $5 =SHA-256, $6 =SHA-512 Algorithm
```

The second field is the salt value, the last field is the hash value of salt+user password.

Answer (score 0):

To identify the hash you can do the following:

1. identify encoding (bin2hex, base64...)
2. check for bit-length
3. identify special format / magic  like special signature bits in bitcoin hashes, salts in password hashes, checksum bits and alike.

In order to "decrypt" it, you most possibly can't. This is the very nature of hashes. They are destructive algos, you can not restore the information lost. In theory, you may be able to create hash collision (using lots of computing power) if the algo is cryptographically weak (eg. md5).

In your case it is most possibly a simple md5 sum.

If it is a computer security quiz, just try to brute-force it. Create md5 hashes of the most possible inputs and compare.